# Transform library from CocoaPod into an internal library in Xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, matlab-spm

I use a library called SVProgressHUD from "https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD".

It works properly on my project, but this library is a CocoaPod library. I removed and migrate all other libraries from CocoaPod to SPM(or transform it into an internal library), but I was not able to migrate the SVProgressHUD library to SPM.

This library is created entirely in ObjC and because of that if I copy and paste the folder inside my project, the "import SVProgressHUD" shows and error

No such module 'SVProgressHUD'

I was able to import using "Objective-C Bridging Header" and using the path file of "SVProgressHUD.h", but I need to remove all imports "import SVProgressHUD" to make it to work.

I see that some libraries imported in my project using SPM use a "module.modulemap" file.

Is it possible to use a "module.modulemap" or something else to maintain the code "import SVProgressHUD" in my files ?